# Add image to Crystal reports from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

i have an issue, im trying to replace an image programatically from vb.net in crystal reports.

this is what i do:

```
Dim facturacion As New dtFactura()
rowDatosFactura.Logo = "F:\imgtest.png"
facturacion.DatosFactura.AddDatosFacturaRow(rowDatosFactura)
```

i set the image path to a dataset

then add the string in te dataset to replace the image in crystal reports

under cyrstal reports i have added an ole picture object

inside the object i have changed the formula with this

```
{DatosFactura.Logo}
```

this is what i have in the formula editor for the picture object, but when i run the code, it doesnt replace the image.

i generate the report this way

```
 Dim _factura As New Factura()
 Private _datosreporte As dtFactura
 _factura.SetDataSource(_datosreporte)
 crwFactura.ReportSource = _factura
 crwFactura.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.ToolPanelViewType.None
```

any idea what to do?

Edit1: I have checked the dataset and its not empty, it contains the path i have set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution, for anybody having the same issue.

the main thing is to convert the image to byte()

then pass the byte() to the row like this

```
rowDatosFactura.Logo = ConvertImageFiletoBytes("F:\logo.jpg")
```

the method to convert the image to byte is this

```
 Public Function ConvertImageFiletoBytes(ByVal ImageFilePath As String) As Byte()
        Dim _tempByte() As Byte = Nothing
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(ImageFilePath) = True Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("Image File Name Cannot be Null or Empty", "ImageFilePath")
            Return Nothing
        End If
        Try
            Dim _fileInfo As New IO.FileInfo(ImageFilePath)
            Dim _NumBytes As Long = _fileInfo.Length
            Dim _FStream As New IO.FileStream(ImageFilePath, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
            Dim _BinaryReader As New IO.BinaryReader(_FStream)
            _tempByte = _BinaryReader.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(_NumBytes))
            _fileInfo = Nothing
            _NumBytes = 0
            _FStream.Close()
            _FStream.Dispose()
            _BinaryReader.Close()
            Return _tempByte
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
```